# Use regex to validate that input is only matches

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to validate a string of text: `.Foo().Bar(20).Baz(Hello)` which could be any number of repetitions of the below pattern:

```
\.(?<exName>[A-Z,a-z]+)\((?<exVal>[^)]+)?\)
```

This correctly provides three matches: **("Foo",*empty*), ("Bar","20"), and ("Baz","Hello")**.

Unfortunately, the following test string provides three matches; but in context of my requirements, the string is invalid because of the extra stuff:

```
.Foo().Bar(20)k.Baz(Hello)hgjfvg
```

How can I fix this to correctly return three matches, but also include the requirement that the given string must be comprised of one or more matches and no extraneous text?

Comment: Did you look up how to indicate then end of a line in a regex?

Comment: @Scott yes, but the expression cannot include end line $ as then it will only return one match. Likewise if I were to include a start line ^, it would only match once.

Comment: That what groups are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can repeat the whole pattern and append anchors,  and then in C# get the values of the [Group.Captures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=net-6.0) property to get the values of the named groups.

```
^(?:\.(?<exName>[A-Za-z]+)\((?<exVal>[^()]*)\))+$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YPoful/1) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/CXQHxg).

As an example zipping both group collections and matching single lines:

```
string pattern = @"\A(?:\.(?<exName>[A-Za-z]+)\((?<exVal>[^()]*)\))+\z";
        
var strings = new List<string>() {
    ".Foo().Bar(20).Baz(Hello)",
    ".Foo().Bar(30)k.Baz(Hi)hgjfvg",
    ".Foo(test).Bar(40).Baz(Bye)"
    };
foreach (var input in strings)
{
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
    {
        m.Groups["exName"]
        .Captures.Select(c => c.Value)
        .Zip(
            m.Groups["exVal"].Captures.Select(c => c.Value),
            (exName, exVal) => exName + " -> " + exVal
        ).ToList()
        .ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
        Console.WriteLine("---------------");
    }
}
```

Output

```
Foo -> 
Bar -> 20
Baz -> Hello
------------------------------
Foo -> test
Bar -> 40
Baz -> Bye
------------------------------
```

Comment: Hmmm...your regex demo does distinguish the different matches, but C# `Matches.Captures` returns 1 Capture.

Comment: FYI I do: `Regex x = new Regex(thepattern)` and then call `x.Matches(test)`

Comment: @NWoodsman 1 Moment, let me add a c# demo to it.

Comment: @NWoodsman You can get the values of the named groups like this https://ideone.com/WZ4OJp

Comment: Ok thanks. Do I need the multiline flag?

Comment: @NWoodsman If you process single lines only then you don't need it.